# Curl command not found when executed from declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, bash, groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy

This works from Jenkins pipeline:

```
stages {
        stage('path') {
            steps {

                sh '''
                    #!/bin/bash
                    path="path/to/xml"
                    info=`curl --user $USER:$PASSWORD ${path}/test.xml | grep '<stakeoverflow>' | tail -1 | sed "s/.*<stakeoverflow>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/stakeoverflow>.*/\\1/"`
                    echo "${info}"
                    '''
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the bash scripts:

**test.sh**

```
function test_call {
    : '
     test comment
    '

    test_commands
    url_commands
    main

}

function test_commands {
    : '
     test comment two
    '
    # get essentails vars
    another_test
    echo "***************${PATH}***************"

    info=`curl --user $USER:$PASSWORD ${PATH}/test.xml | grep '<stakeoverflow>' | tail -1 | sed "s/.*<stakeoverflow>\([^<]*\)<\/stakeoverflow>.*/\1/"`

    echo "info is: ${info}"

}
```

I have tried with also double back slash but popping up the same error as mentioned down below in the question.

When tried this:

```
stage('path') {
            steps {

                sh '''
                set +x
                chmod +x test.sh
                echo "***********loading bash script***********"
                source test.sh
                curl --version
                test_call
                '''
            }
        }
```

It does not help with if """ or '''
I get this output:

```
curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
```

Here is the error:

```
curl: command not found
grep: command not found
tail: command not found
sed: command not found
```

After I added the curl path like this :

```
info=`/usr/bin/curl --user $USER:$PASSWORD ${PATH}/test.xml | grep '<stakeoverflow>' | tail -1 | sed "s/.*<stakeoverflow>\([^<]*\)<\/stakeoverflow>.*/\1/"`
```

I get these errors:

```
grep: command not found
tail: command not found
sed: command not found
```

Seems like something is wrong with ' or ".

**N.B** I tested same scenarios on the same Jenkins node

What am I doing wrong here? I am pretty confused to understand the issue.

Comment: not answer: you can use absolute path for all commands

Comment: I found the issue just now it was the ${PATH} that was causing the curl issue in bash scripts. It works. I just use ${path} which fixed this. It was my stupidity though $PATH (this already an env var in liunx)